# STR_TO_DATE with timezone

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone, str-to-date

I my MySQL (version 5.7.25) database there's have a column, which is full of `varchar(100)` dates like `Fri May 04 08:08:42 UTC 2018`. I need to convert them to date.

So far I've came up with

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Fri May 04 08:08:42 UTC 2018', '%a %b %d %T %Y') AS to_date
```

but it returns null because of the timezone. But if I try:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Fri May 04 08:08:42 2018', '%a %b %d %T %Y') AS to_date
```

... it works perfectly. So is there a way to add a timezone to the date format?

Comment: Do you want to convert the timezone before saving as datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string always contains UTC then you can hard-code it:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Fri May 04 08:08:42 UTC 2018', '%a %b %d %T UTC %Y') AS to_date
-- 2018-05-04 08:08:42
```

If you want to convert the timezone information as well you need to use [`CONVERT_TZ`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(STR_TO_DATE('Fri May 04 08:08:42 UTC 2018', '%a %b %d %T UTC %Y'), '+00:00', 'system')
-- 2018-05-04 13:08:42
-- actual result depends on system timezone
```